# If there is a instability issue inside the control loop, and the control system starts oscillating, what will be the oscillation frequency?

Tags: control-engineering, stability

I have a closed loop controller to control the vehicle on the centerline with a bandwidth of 2 rad/s, and I saw the vehicle keeps oscillating around the centerline in a sinusoid whose period is around 8 to 10 seconds; how could I tell that if the oscillation can indicate that the controller have instability issue?

In other words, if the controller has an instability issue, what is the expected oscillation frequency? Is it related to the natural frequency or bandwidth of the control system?

Comment: There is an open loop system and a closed system. Each has stability properties. If you know your controller perfectly well you could deduce the open loop, but prob with more measurements (e.g. step input or sinusoids). Read thru some intro control theory tutorials...

Comment: Does the period change with the change in forward velocity of the vehicle ? Please give a diagram and a detailed description of the vehicle and the controller. What is the controller ? What is the sensor ? Is the vehicle and its engine/motor and the sensor and the controller linear systems ? Is the center line straight line ? The question needs much more details.

Comment: If any part of your system has non linearity like dead band or hysteresis, oscillations could be unavoidable and not a sign of instability.

Comment: An anecdote about aircraft autopilot systems: there was one airliner  (I forget which, either Boeing or McDonnell-Douglas) which refused to "fly straight" on autopilot. The problem wasn't discovered until passengers and flight crew in the rear of the plane complained about airsickness. It was found that (because the real world system was nonlinear) the "straight ahead" equilibrium point was unstable, but there were two stable equilibrium points at small yaw angles either side of it. Random inputs from turbulence etc kept flip-flopping the autopilot between the two stable equilibrium points.

Comment: ... Note, the plane was stable in straight flight *without* the autopilot but adding the autopilot dynamics to the system made it unstable because of nonlinear dynamic behavior which had been ignored in the autopilot design process.